# How to cancel appointment in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, appointment

I want show the Outlook cancellation form when an appointment is deleted via code in Delphi (program code, otherwise). I am able to delete an item which will delete the item from Outlook (please note the item does have recipient also). But I would like to show the cancellation form that Outlook uses when the user clicks on the **Cancel Meeting** button of the appointment item.

Is this possible?

Secondly, if this is not possible, then when the appointment is deleted via code (that is. appointment.Delete) I would like to send out the same cancel meeting email that outlook generates to each recipient. At the moment, when the appointment is deleted, even if there are recipient no email is sent.

Please help.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions. You will get more help on [SuperUser.](http://superuser.com) Edit: Reread question. This is iffy. I'm not sure which one would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Set the MeetingStatus property to olMeetingCanceled and call Send. You can then delete the appointment.

Comment: If I sent a Vcard with a meeting for someone else, by setting the status to cancelled on my outlook will it automatically cancel it for the other person as well? (They are added as required attendees)

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing - you are sending a vCard (which is for contacts) and at the same time you are setting the MeetingStatus property on the receiving side?

Comment: it's not Vacrd sorry, it's Vcal such as `oAppointment.ForwardAsVcal();`

Comment: I am still not sure what you are asking. IF I understand correctly, cancelling an appointment for one attendee (not the organizer), will not affect the appointment for another attendee.

Comment: wich I want is this: I have an appointment in the "local" outlook calendar let's say it this way, and I send the Vcal to another users outlook so he adds it do the calendar, what I want to do is when I cancell the appointment in the "local" outlook and delete it from the calendar, delete it also in the other persons calendar without asking her to do it. is it even possible to access someone else outlook calendar?

Comment: You can always send a meeting cancelation, but whether it will be honored is up to the recipient. In case of Exchange, you can try to access the attendee's mailbox, you need to have an explicit right to do so.

Comment: I've took the first aproach of sending an email saying the meeting has been cancelled. I think it was the best aproach since I couldn't access his/hers mailbox or the calendar